# Difference in table borders in PDF generated with PhantomJS and Puppeteer Sharp at zoom levels > 100% in PDF viewer

Tags: css, pdf, phantomjs, border, puppeteer-sharp

I am having an issue converting a function generating PDFs with PhantomJS to use Puppeteer Sharp instead.

The output from Puppeteer Sharp should be as similar as possible as the output when using PhantomJS.

Having the two PDFs they look similar at 100% zoom level.

When zooming to 125 % (using PDFescape) the table borders does not look identical anymore. All borders are defined as `border-bottom: 0.1pt solid #323e48;`

Any thoughts on how to avoid this problem occurring at zoom level > 100 ?

Orig (PhantomJS) 100% / 125%

[image: Orig 100%]
[image: Orig 125%]

New (Puppeteer Sharp) 100% / 125%

[image: New 100%]
[image: New 125%]

Comment: PuppeteerSharp will use the Print to PDF tool of Chromium. PhantomJS uses QtWebKit. Nothing guarantees that both engines generate the same PDF output.

Comment: If you would share a minimal PDF file from both cases, someone could look at your PDF files and perhaps discover something that could help you. Without those PDF files, all you've done is shared some (admittedly pleasant looking) pictures of tables.